# Mysql Query STR_TO_DATE AND DATE_ADD

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a query Mysql,

```
SELECT orereparto.settimana AS 'Sett', (CASE giorno
    WHEN 'lunedi' THEN STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y')
    WHEN 'martedi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    WHEN 'mercoledi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    WHEN 'giovedi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
    WHEN 'venerdi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 4 DAY) 
    WHEN 'sabato' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN 'domenica' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
    ELSE 0
END) AS 'Giorno', reparti.nomerep AS 'Reparto', SUM(orereparto.orereps) AS 'Ore' FROM orereparto INNER JOIN smk ON orereparto.idsmk = smk.idsmk INNER JOIN reparti ON orereparto.idrep = reparti.idrep WHERE smk.nomesmk = 'Stalingrado' AND orereparto.settimana = '21/07/2014' GROUP BY reparti.nomerep,giorno ORDER BY reparti.nomerep ASC
```

the server answer me this:

```
# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual That corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHEN' Wednesday 'THEN DATE_ADD (STR_TO_DATE (orereparto.settimana,'% d,% m,% Y ')' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE_ADD` takes a comma before the `interval`statement:

```
SELECT orereparto.settimana AS 'Sett', (CASE giorno
    WHEN 'lunedi' THEN STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y')
    WHEN 'martedi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
    WHEN 'mercoledi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y'), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    WHEN 'giovedi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y'), INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
    WHEN 'venerdi' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y'), INTERVAL 4 DAY) 
    WHEN 'sabato' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y'), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN 'domenica' THEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y'), INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
    ELSE 0
END) AS 'Giorno', reparti.nomerep AS 'Reparto', SUM(orereparto.orereps) AS 'Ore'
FROM orereparto INNER JOIN
     smk
     ON orereparto.idsmk = smk.idsmk INNER JOIN
     reparti
     ON orereparto.idrep = reparti.idrep
WHERE smk.nomesmk = 'Stalingrado' AND orereparto.settimana = '21/07/2014'
GROUP BY reparti.nomerep,giorno
ORDER BY reparti.nomerep ASC;
```

You can also add `intervals` to a date just by saying:

```
STR_TO_DATE(orereparto.settimana,'%d,%m,%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But you are mixing the two syntaxes.